# Does there exist an open-source distributed logging library?

Tags: language-agnostic, logging, monitoring, distributed, cluster-computing

I'm talking about a library that would allow me to log events from different machines and would align these events on a "global" time axis with sufficiently high precision.

Actually, I'm asking because I've written such a thing myself in the course of a cluster computing project, I found it *terrifically* useful, and I was surprised that I couldn't find any analogues.

Therefore, the point is whether something like this exists (and I better contribute to it) or nothing exists (and I better write an open-source analogue of my solution).

Here are the features that I'd expect from such a library:

- Independence on the clock offset between different machines
- Timing precision on the order of at least milliseconds, preferably microseconds
- Scalability to thousands of concurrent logging processes, with at least several megabytes of aggregated logs per second
- Soft real-time operation (t.i. I don't want to collect 200 big logs from 200 machines and then compute clock offsets and merge them - I want to see what happens "live", perhaps with a small lag like 10s)

Comment: The time sync and the logging are usually carried out by two different libraries. But I don't see firsthand what is the difference between your approach and doing that using two packages ...

Comment: Having time sync and logging by two different libraries is a workaround. The difference is that if they're done together, I obtain a real-time flowing precisely timed log of all the events in my system; I want to see it in near-real-time, not get it by a bunch of aposteriori scripts on saved logs. I tried that too, and the difference in productivity (analysis, experimentation) is dramatic.

Comment: Did any of this ever get open-sourced?  Or was the solution to just use Scribe?

Comment: @MachoMatt Yes - http://code.google.com/p/greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook's contribution in the matter is called '[Scribe](https://github.com/facebook/scribe)'.

Excerpt:

> Scribe is a server for aggregating streaming log data. It is designed to scale to a very large number of nodes and be robust to network and node failures. There is a scribe server running on every node in the system, configured to aggregate messages and send them to a central scribe server (or servers) in larger groups.

...

> Scribe is implemented as a thrift service using the non-blocking C++ server. The installation at facebook runs on thousands of machines and reliably delivers tens of billions of messages a day.

The API is Thrift-based, so you have a good platform coverage, but in case you're looking for simple integration for Java you may want to have a look at Digg's [log4j appender for Scribe](https://github.com/lenn0x/Scribe-log4j-Appender).

Comment: Yes, I know about Scribe, but IIRC it doesn't provide a global time axis and is therefore useless for finding distributed performance bottlenecks.

Comment: Why github project seems quite lonely?

Answer (score 1):

You could use log4j/log4net targeting a central syslog daemon.  log4j has a builtin [SyslogAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SyslogAppender.html), and in log4net you can do it as shown [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RemoteSyslogAppender.html).  log4cpp docs [here](http://log4cpp.sourceforge.net/api/classlog4cpp_1_1RemoteSyslogAppender.html).

There are Windows implementations of Syslog around if you don't have a Unix system to hand for this.

Comment: This just won't be 1) fast enough (1 network RPC request to send to syslog, 50000 logging events per second = too many RPC requests per second) and 2) precise enough (timestamps of arrival will, under such heavy load, differ from timestamps of generation by much more than a few microseconds).

Comment: @jkff - and you want all that for free? :-) Try Splunk if you cannot find it - http://www.splunk.com/

Comment: I already have all that, and it's really quite a small piece of code. I was just wondering whether I've invented the wheel, and whether someone would be happy if I open-sourced my stuff.

Comment: @jkff: Could you elaborate on how you implemented the "global time axis"? Do you have a central synchronization server (ala ntp), or?

Comment: Records are registered with occurence timestamps. Clients send records to the server. Server uses the trivial Cristian's algorithm to compute clock offsets between himself and the clients, and adjusts the timestamps of records accordingly, so all timestamps end up being expressed on server's time axis. That's it :)

Comment: @jkff: Thanks for the explanation! When do you plan on open sourcing this?

Comment: In the nearest 1-2 weeks, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Use Chukwa, Its Open source and Large scale Log Monitoring System

Comment: Could you please elaborate on advantages of Chuckwa?